# How could I use mobx in nodejs but not browser?

Tags: mobx

I try to use mobx in nodejs but the script is not work.

```
(async function () {
  const mobx = require('./mobx.umd.min.js')
  // example 2, array of primitives
  // observes computed value, works
  const { observable, computed, autorun } = mobx;

  var numbers = observable([1, 2, 3]);
  autorun(() => {

    console.log(numbers);
  });
  numbers.push(4); //autorun does not trigger
  numbers.push(4); //autorun does not trigger
})();
```

but the script works in broswer:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx/5.15.4/mobx.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      // example 2, array of primitives
      // observes computed value, works
      const { observable, computed, autorun } = mobx;

      var numbers = observable([1, 2, 3]);
      autorun(() => {
        window.numbers = numbers;
        const app = document.querySelector("#app");
        console.log(`numbers`, numbers);
        app.innerHTML = "<p>" + numbers.join(", ") + "</p>";
      });
      numbers.push(4); //autorun does not trigger
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use mobx in nodejs, How could I use mobx in nodejs directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing `numbers` array inside Node.js `autorun`, but you have not changed it, so there is not reason to MobX to `autorun`. Observers (e.g. autorun, computed, observer and etc.) only react when something was changed.

You only changed array content, not the array itself. So if your code was something like that:

```
  autorun(() => {
    console.log(numbers.map(x => x);
  });
```

It would work as expected, because here you actually referencing array content. And browser version works because you are using `numbers.join` and referencing array content with that call.

Next time try to test identical cases in both environments just to be sure that the error in not in your code!